# Refreshing a TAB of TabHost

Tags: android, tabs, refresh

What's the best way to refresh the current tab so that onCreate is called again and the TAB menu of TabHost are kept untouched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a method which contain all operations of `onCreate()` and just call that method in onCreate() and on your TAB change.

Answer (score 0):

There is an method in Android to initialize tabs. In that on clicking any tab, an activity related to it will start and the view will be set of the activity. Your tabHost won't be affected. The life cycle of android will be followed. So when u click other tab, the previous goes into pause state. So handle all things in onResume().

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec spec1 ;
TabSpec spec2 ;
TabSpec spec3 ;

spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("spec1").setIndicator("spec1").setContent(new Intent (mainActivity.this, spec1.class ));
spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("spec2").setIndicator("spec2").setContent(new Intent (mainActivity.this, spec2.class ));
spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("spec3").setIndicator("spec3").setContent(new Intent (mainActivity.this, spec3.class ));

tabHost.addTab(spec1);
tabHost.addTab(spec3);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);
tabHost.setup();
```

Add logs to verify it.

Comment: Click the V mark on left side of answer to accept the answer if you are clear and close the question. And you will gain reputation also.. ;-)